# Moq Unsupported expression

Tags: c#, moq

Пытаюсь замокать метод репозитория `AnyAsync` чтобы всегда возвращал `false`, но при попытке получаю исключение:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.AnyAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Order, bool>>>(), CancellationToken)
> Extension methods (here: RepositoryAsyncExtensions.AnyAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

```
var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Order, Guid>>();

mockRepository.Setup(x => x.AnyAsync(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Order, bool>>>(), default)).Returns(() => false);

var service = new PublicOrderAppService(mockRepository.Object);
```

Comment: `.ReturnsAsync`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov к сожалению не помогло